# Error in getting Oracle DB_NAME with sys_context

Tags: sql, oracle

I used to operate in more than one database at a time, but when ever I get confused on which DB i have logged in I use sys_context to know DB I'm working on. But now I'm not getting any results for it, neither any error message. What could be the problem?

```
  1* select sys_context('user_env','db_name') from dual
SQL> /

SYS_CONTEXT('USER_ENV','DB_NAME')
----------------------------------------------------------


SQL>
```

When  I try other way  I know I get this error. its probably because I don't have admin access

```
SQL> select utl_inaddr.get_host_address from dual;
select utl_inaddr.get_host_address from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_INADDR", line 19
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_INADDR", line 40
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_env` should be `USERENV`:

```
select sys_context('USERENV','DB_NAME') from dual
```

Comment: Thanks! how wud I be so dumb :D but why wasn't I getting any error?